# Lost variable after open a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file named **index.html.**
And a javascript file named **test.js**

The javascript will open a new tab and load an image on it.
I also defined some function to resize the image.

The problem is that if I close the original page then I could not resize the image.
It seems that all in variables and functions I defined in the javascript are gone.

Is there anyone know how to fix this problem???

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Normally when you open a new tab you would expect it to be an independent page that doesn't care about the original page's variables.

Comment: Thats the expected behavior. Please, specify what you are trying to do, what did you do to accomplish it, and what failed.

Comment: This is normal JS behavior.  You need to use cookies, localStorage, server-side variables or some other method to have JS variables stored in memory persist across pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to those variables in your new window, you should copy them to that window's contentWindow. E.g.,

```
var x = 'original variable',
    newWin = window.open(...);
if (newWin) {
    newWin.x = x;
}
```

Note, however, that these will be copies and not references to the original variables, so changing them in the new window will not update the copies in the original window. To link them, you'd need to set up a bridge using events or postMessage.